# Dotnet CLI: How to know the latest version value is actual on the current day?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-cli

From Microsoft documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/)):

[image]

How to know the latest version value is actual on the current day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up the package using Nuget.org, see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet/). I'm not sure if it's possible to add a version reference that always resolves to the latest available version, as the Nuget dependency manager [tries to resolve to the lowest applicable package available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#dependency-updates-during-package-install).